# What is the best way to store often used (not changeable) List, Map?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-mvc, ehcache

What is the best way to store often used (not changeable) List, Map?
Is it better to use `@Cacheable` over creating list in the service layer on `@PostConstruct`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say `@Cacheable` is better because you're not tied to a specific caching implementation. Also it's less intrusive on the code. As specified on [Spring Reference Manual Section 29.3.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable), caching a method that finds a book by ISBN just looks like this:

```
@Cacheable("books")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}
```